# XSS attack on to get root priveleges

Tags: xss, operating-systems, rootkits

Is there any way of execute an xss attack inside a Linux machine to get to sudo mode? I know Linux is designed to separate the two types of user. 
I guess, i don't really know but I guess diferent distros use diferent ddl language.

Also: May I use C language to do a similar (I know that admin processes work on normal users on windows) script but for windows?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.  [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) is client-side injection used to attack browsers, meaning the attack manipulates the webpage which shows up in the user's browser.   In order to perform XSS attacks, you need to use HTML/JavaScript (C will not work).   As XSS is an attack against the browser, the only way to attack a linux system is if the browser is running on a linux system.

Theoretically, if you could leverage the XSS attack to get the browser to load a malicious Flash object which exploits a buffer overflow/other bug, you could get arbitrary code execution on the system, and then exploit a privilege escalation bug to get root access.  Theoretically do-able, but it relies on many other bugs to do the actually privilege escalation, and there are probably much easier ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: got it! thanks! and is not a goal, is just for curiosity and to learn more so thank you!